# Как создать объект Person (или User) в Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

На странице login.jsp есть форма авторизации:

```html
<c:url value="/perform_login" var="login" />
    <form action="${login}" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Войти</button>
    </form>
```

При входе на сайт эта форма проверяется спрингом следующим образом:

```java
HttpSecurity http
.........
http.formLogin()
          .loginPage("/login")
          .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
          .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
```

Я пытаюсь получить **username** и **password** в контроллере

```java
@RequestMapping (method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public void logInForm(@RequestParam(value="username") String login, 
              @RequestParam(value="password") String password, Model model) {
System.out.println("dead code");
  }
```

но спринг почему-то обходит контроллер стороной (не видит его, и перенаправляет на главную страницу приложения в случае удачной аутентификации)... Если заменить 2 строки на странице с формой `<c:url value="/perform_login" var="login" /> <form action="${login}" method="post">`
одной строкой `<form action="login" method="post">` то тогда контроллер становится видимым... Как правильно получить username и password и/или создать объект **Person** (User) в **Spring Security**?